# Searching number in file

Tags: awk

How to write program in awk or in something more appropriate, if it is needed, that will search and write numbers?

I have a file

```
0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000
   -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000
   -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000
   -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000
   -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000
    0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000
   -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000
    0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000
   -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000  -0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
    0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000

 CHECK OF COMPUTED DEPENDENT VARIABLES FROM NORMAL EQUATIONS

   0.0921839
 -10.1319866
   3.6264119
  11.7262830
 -68.8050967
   0.4522270
   0.3373249
 -34.8902892
 -27.7340970
   1.3273557
  23.1789217
 -21.5330918
  25.0183830
 -41.1342361
  -9.4139492
  67.1457087
 -86.1216513
   0.4522270
   0.9082617
  -3.1807870
  -1.9716431
  -1.1840182
  -3.7907675
  -1.4510456
  -1.1857174
  -4.8308521
  -1.3112015
   1.1611722
  -6.1369640
  -3.5550976
  -4.7666450
  -0.6706241
  -2.2754214
  -2.9594634
  -1.9888614
  -0.9457585
  -0.9477964
 -11.1808337
  -9.6823234
  -6.0165193
  -4.6256076
 SUM OF ABSOLUTE VALUES OF CHECKS IS 0.188070D-10
                      Input-Output in F Format

No.  Curve    Input Param.        Correction     Output Param.    Standard Deviation
 9      0     43.8999000000      2.4976090669     46.3975090669      0.3593736560
10      0      0.0883000000     -0.0008250571      0.0874749429      0.0006398321
11      0      2.5816650000     -0.0033525536      2.5783124464      0.0109309501
12      0      1.0000000000      0.0481656121      1.0481656121      0.0288356492
13      0      1.0000000000     -3.1951648165     -2.1951648165      2.0603892225
14      0      0.0000000000     -0.0002127349     -0.0002127349      0.0017416849
15      0      0.2175000000      0.0015097548      0.2190097548      0.0015804101
16      0     80.4198910000     -4.3952312032     76.0246597968      0.1589276670
17      0      1.0000000000     -2.5673410799     -1.5673410799      0.0871801072
18      0      1.0000000000   -205.4932338114   -204.4932338114     14.4204106262
19      0      3.0000000000     -0.2245759531      2.7754240469      0.0822226758
20      0      1.9424000000      0.1257878585      2.0681878585      0.0430855010
21      0      1.0000000000    -18.7946060528    -17.7946060528      2.0771181978
22      0      1.0000000000     -2.8342434886     -1.8342434886      0.2995629339
23      0      3.5047300000     -0.3237559753      3.1809740247      0.0128735907
24      0      5.5942300000      0.6858315083      6.2800615083      0.0486118539
25      0      0.3827000000     -0.0227502151      0.3599497849      0.0041910161
```

And I would like to get

```
46.397509
0.359373
0.087474
0.000639
....
```

So how to write something like 
if row after string Input-Output in F Format begin with 9 then write $5 in format %2.6f (6 decimal places) and to next row write $6 in format %2.6f (6 decimal places)

There is a similar table in the input file, so I need to search only the first row that start with this number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** After chatting with OP got to know that we need to print 5th and 6th fields from Input_file after line matches `Input-Output in F Format` in Input_file as follows.

```
awk '/Input-Output in F Format/{flag=1;next} flag && ($0 ~ /^[0-9]/ ||  $0 ~ /^ [0-9]+/){printf("%.06f\n%.06f\n",$5,$6)}' Input_file
```

---

---

Is this you want, not clear but giving it a try. Here `$(NF-1)` means 2nd last and `$NF` means last field of current line. So you could change field numbers as per your need too.

```
awk 'FNR>4{printf("%.06f\n%.06f\n",$(NF-1),$NF)}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
46.397509
0.359374
0.087475
0.000640
......... so on.....
```

***EDIT:*** Since OP's Input_file could have TAB delimited data so suggesting changing `awk` to `awk  -F'\t'` to OP here.

Also in case you want to see column numbers in a line then you could run following.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print "field_number",i,"field value",$i}}' Input_file
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
awk '/^$/{flag=""} /Input-Output in F Format/{flag=1;next} flag && ($0 ~ /^[0-9]/ || $0 ~ /^ [0-9]+/) && ($0 !~ /[2][89]/ && $0 !~ /[3][01]/){printf("%.06f\n%.06f\n",$5,$6)}' Input_file
```

OR adding a non-one liner form of above solution now:

```
awk '
/^$/{
  flag=""
}
/Input-Output in F Format/{
  flag=1
  next
}
flag && ($0 ~ /^[0-9]/ || $0 ~ /^ [0-9]+/) && ($0 !~ /[2][89]/ && $0 !~ /[3][01]/){
  printf("%.06f\n%.06f\n",$5,$6)
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: @Elisabeth, please post input data in your post itself NOT in external links. Also please do let me know if this code didn't work for you, if NOT then mention complete details of your question.

Comment: I got another numbers. The input file is big, can I add such file in question?

Comment: @Elisabeth, add sample of them not full file, add samples which look like your actual file and mention all conditions of expected output in your post. Let me know then.

Comment: @Elisabeth, is your file tab delimited? If yes then try to execute `awk 
 -F'\t' 'FNR>4{printf("%.06f\n%.06f\n",$(NF-1),$NF)}'  Input_file`?

Comment: @Elisabeth, also you could run this command `awk -F'\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print "field number:",i," field value= ,$i}} Input_file` once to get all field's values and then may be you could print the values whichever you want?

Comment: The first code gives 
9.000000
9.000000
10.000000
10.000000
....
 and the second show > in termanal, when I write code with input file and press enter

Comment: @Elisabeth, ok seems your Input_file is having more fields than you showed, so try running command to know your field number which I have added now in my EDIT solution and they you will come to know which field you want to print then change `$(NF-1)` and `$NF` with respective field numbers, let me know?

Comment: Thank you, i works with input file in question, but the original input file is more complicated - there are data before this table. Is it possible to say that your code should work from a sring like 'Input-Output in F Format'? It would be better if you can see the whole input file in external links.

Comment: @Elisabeth, not sure what do you mean by F format input, output? You could check field numbers which you want to print by command which I added in EDIT solution once and try? That EDIT command will print field numbers with values which you can use it my very first command to get output. Let me know if you get it?

Comment: I did it and I set this number in your code and it works with the input file from the question, however, the real input file conclude more data before and after the part I show you. So my question is, whether it is possible to say where is should start. 'Input-Output in F Format' I mean the string in input file, which can definite, where the table is.

Comment: @Elisabeth, sorry I am not getting it, you have to show example of that input and output in your post in code tags and let me know then.

Comment: Can I show you in some way the whole real input file? It would be very helpful to understant each other. It has 28500 rows so it is not approprite to load it here. It is in the first comment in first link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185312/discussion-between-ravindersingh13-and-elisabeth).

Comment: Please can I ask you for explanation of code? 
`'/^$/{flag=""} /Input-Output in F Format/{flag=1;next} flag &&` What this ^$ mean? Thank you