# awk - finding numbers from file

Tags: awk

Can you explain me this command please?

```
awk '/^$/{flag=""} /Input-Output in F Format/{flag=1;next} flag && ($0 ~ /^[0-9]/ || $0 ~ /^ [0-9]+/) && ($0 !~ /[2][89]/ && $0 !~ /[3][01]/){printf("%.06f\n%.06f\n",$5,$6)}'
```

'Input-Output in F Format' is a string in file

Thank you

Comment: what is the question?  which part is not clear?

Comment: I am beginner and almost nothing is clear. I understand only $5,$6 are number of columns, %.06f menas format of number - 6 decimal places. Flag restrict the area of file, with that it works, but either this part is not clear.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800568/searching-number-in-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the 5th and 6th numerical fields in lines that begin with a digit or a space followed by multiple digits but do not contain any of 28,29,30 or 31, and occur between a line containing “Input-Output in F Format” and an empty line.

I wonder how hard it would be to write an awk2english translator....

/^$/{flag=“"}     --  when there is a blank line, clear the flag.

/Input-Output in F Format/{flag=1;next}  -- when long string, set flag and skip other rules (next)

flag &&  ....   -- when flag is set, perform the numeric rules.

($0 ~ /^[0-9]/ || $0 ~ /^ [0-9]+/)   -- line begins with a digit, or a space followed by multiple digits

($0 !~ /[2][89]/ && $0 !~ /[3][01]/)  -- line does not contain 28,29,30 or 31.

With respect to your file in 53800568:

awk '/^[0-9 ][0-9]+[ \t]/ && NF == 6 { printf("%f\n", $5); }'

Worked for me.

Comment: /^$/{flag=""} /Input-Output in F Format/{flag=1;next} flag     what does  /^$/ mean? {flag=""} is the empty line?

Comment: That is a variable in awk; in this script it is used to set the context (when the string is recognized) and reset when a blank line is.   It has to be set to enable matching the numbers.   There is a terrific book on awk “The Awk Programming Language” which covers the original awk (not gnu extanity) https://ia902309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf

Comment: Why it doesn't work with this file?  stackoverflow.com/questions/53800568/searching-number-in-file

Comment: It looks, to me, like that file has an empty line after the Input-Output...   That empty line will reset flag.

Comment: OK, so have you got any idea for this situation - how to restrict this area?